# Why is $\epsilon = \dfrac{\alpha}{2}$ in this lemma of $\int_0^1f(t)\,dt = 0$ if and only if $f(t)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

> Lemma: Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous with $f(t) \ge 0$ for all $t \in [0,1].$ Then $\int_0^1f(t)\,dt = 0$ if and only if $f(t)=0$ for all $t \in [0,1]$.

For the non-trivial part, the author did by contradiction:

> If $f$ is not identically $0$, since $f \geq 0$, there exists $t_0$ such that $f(t_0) > 0$. Let $\alpha = f(t_0)$ and $\epsilon = \dfrac{\alpha}{2}$. For this value of $\epsilon$, by continuity of $f$ at $t_0$, there is a $\delta$ such that $f(t) \in \left(\dfrac{\alpha}{2},\dfrac{3\alpha}{2}\right)$ for $t \in(t_0-\delta,t_0+\delta)$
>
> which implies
> $$\int_0^1f(t)\,dt \ge \int_{t_0-\delta}^{t_0+\delta} f(t)\,dt \ge \int_{t_0-\delta}^{t_0+\delta} \dfrac{\alpha}{2}\,dt = \alpha\delta > 0$$

My point is, why did author chose $\epsilon = \dfrac{\alpha}{2}$?

What I usually do is to backtrace $\epsilon$. So, I assumed $\epsilon = k $.

By the definition of continuity, for a given $\epsilon, $

$$ |f(t) - f(t_0)| < \epsilon $$
$$ f(t) \in \left(f(t_0)-\epsilon \, ,f(t_0)+\epsilon\right) $$
$$ f(t) \in \left(\alpha-k \, ,\alpha+k\right) $$

There exists $\delta$ such that, for $t \in(t_0-\delta,t_0+\delta)$

$$\int_0^1f(t)\,dt \ge \int_{t_0-\delta}^{t_0+\delta} f(t)\,dt \ge \int_{t_0-\delta}^{t_0+\delta} k\,dt = 2k\delta > 0$$

I can get the same result by just having $\epsilon$ as it is. Then why did the author chose $\epsilon = \dfrac{\alpha}{2}$?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you choose $$\epsilon=k$$

You will get

$$\int_0^1f(t)dt\ge \int_{t_0-\delta}^{t_0+\delta}f(t)dt$$
$$\ge \int_{t_0-\delta}^{t_0+\delta}(\alpha-k)dt$$

$$=2\delta(\alpha-k)$$
You can, if you want, take $\epsilon=\frac{\alpha}{3} $

Comment: Oops. Silly mistake. Agree.